# Como crear un scroll infinite como el de whatsapp

Tags: ionic3

Ayuda alguien puede ayudarme,estoy trabajando  en un proyecto de `ionic 3` y `firebase`.

Estoy realizando un chat, utilizo el `scroll infinite` para que me vaya mostrando los registros de `firebase` del mas nuevo al mas antiguo  de 10 en 10, el detalle está que necesito que esos registros se vayan mostrando hacia arriba con forme yo haga `scroll` hacia abajo y no mostrarlos hacia abajo como lo hace actualmente un `ngFor` para que se hagan una idea de lo que necesito es como ver la funcionalidad de *whatsapp* que cuando se quiere ver los mensajes viejos o anteriores se hace `scroll` hacia abajo y va cargando los mensajes hacia arriba.